# Google Analytics API: How many goal conversions (contact form submission) were triggered from the organic traffic by a certain landing page?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, goal-tracking

I think it's all in the title but to reformulate, let's say:

- I want to find out how to report the number of times a landing page "www.mywebsite.com/a-landing-page-with-engaging-content" was at the origin of a form submission.
- I want to use the API, therefore I am trying to find to right elements for the API query.

So far, what I do is, somehow, considering the problem from the scope of the goal funnel visualization: *how many times this page was the "GoalPreviousStep2" (PreviousStep1 being the form to fill in)*:

Here are the elements of the query:

**Metric:** ga:goal3Completions

**Dimension:** ga:goalPreviousStep2

**Filter:** ga:goalPreviousStep2==www.mywebsite.com/a-landing-page-with-engaging-content

**Segment:** gaid::-5 (Because I am only interested of what happen in sessions from the organic traffic)

**max-results:** 1

Normally, if during the date range, 5 people came from Google on the website, navigate until the "page" and then clicked on the contact button from this "page", fill and complete the form, I should see 5 as a result. Am I wrong ?

This is so far the best solution I happened to find, since I do not have any goal value specified nor I know what value that I should use.

Actually I am posting here because that seems something really essential to measure and I wonder if I am not "re-inventing a polygonal wheel".

**Can someone tell me if it's a correct approach to to what I intend to do ? is there any other/better way, or limitations with this method ??**

Thank you for the help.